# How do I swing a polearm while on horseback?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

Most polearms come with a swing and thrust damage number, but while on horseback, the default attack seems to be only thrust.  How do I swing a polearm while on horseback?

Comment: What game is it?

Comment: It's probably not allowed, at least if the horse gets any say in the matter.

Comment: @toast the game is in the tag

Comment: Can you use any other two-handed weapons in two-handed fashion while on a horse?  Having ridden a horse a time or two in my youth, I don't know that the logistic required of two-handed attacks from a horse would be very effective and/or comfortable.

Comment: most polearms damage is in the thrust any way..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that most polearms in the game do not support a swing attack while mounted.  The only such pole arms that allow for 2 handed swings are the [hafted blades](http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Polearms) and their variants.  These are the same weapons that the Khergit lancers sometimes use, which is how I noticed their uniqueness.